# No such framework "susy" using compass

Tags: compass-sass, susy-compass, susy-sass

I'm trying to create a compass project using the susy grid.

```
$ compass create --using susy test
No such framework: "susy"
```

I am using git-bash on Windows 7. I have Ruby 2.0.0p451, Sass 3.3.8 and Compass 0.12.6 installed. I have `require 'susy'` in my config.rb file.

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause, but Compass 0.12 doesn't work with Sass 3.3. You need to upgrade to the pre-release version of Compass 1.0.

Comment: Ah. I see... Using gem install compass --pre worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Eric M Suzanne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930386/eric-m-suzanne), I installed a pre-release version of compass 1.0 (now available as 1.0.1 stable) using `gem install compass --pre`.

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and i am working with compass so, be sure that you first have:

```
$ gem install compass-rails
$ gem install sass-rails
$ gem install susy
```

voilà